# Getting Nearest Latitude and Longitude Value of a Hospital by passing a Current Latitude and Longitude in a URL

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

initially i am getting current Latitude and Longitude value of user. After i pass current Latitude and Longitude value of user through this url. it shows the many nearest hospital location in google map.How can i retrieve the Longitude and Longitude value of the Hospitals.

URL To find nearest Hospital

```
            http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospital&mrt=yp&sll=12.972526,79.157692&output=kml
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use google places search api to achieve that, it looks like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

here's the documentation:https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search